# Bootstrap responsive horizontal layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a Bootstrap layout but I need it to be responsive and not sure how to do this horizontally.
[image: Here's an image]

How can I make that layout using standard Bootstrap layout but also have it be responsive? I currently have it with the "labels" in one fluid row and the inputs in another fluid row but when it is "shrunk", the labels no longer fit with the inputs.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - if you're using a fluid row, won't it just widen to fill the width of the parent? What is your desired effect with responsiveness?

Comment: The labels are on one fluid row and the inputs are in another below it. The problem lies when the responsive flow goes into affect, the labels are aligned on top of each other "in one row" and the inputs are aligned on top of each other "in one row", the labels are no longer "associated" with their inputs. I did see the  control-group, control-label, controls selectors and may check that out.

Comment: See the .form-horizontal sample here:   http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms    The only problem with this is that I separated my form into a tabbed interface and allow the user to edit all fields in the form, via the tabs, before submitting. I don't think the .form-horizontal selector will work for me but the others might.

Comment: Have you considered nesting by making a single .row-fluid with five .spans inside it and two more .row-fluids inside each span? This way there is only one top level row, and the labels/fields should stay together.

Comment: Now that's a thought, let me try.

Comment: @hayk.mart - please post your last comment as answer.

Comment: Would you also post a skeleton of what you are imagining? I just can't quite get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered nesting by making a single .row-fluid with five .spans inside it and two more .row-fluids inside each span? This way there is only one top level row, and the labels/fields should stay together.

http://jsfiddle.net/hmartiro/D2RLR/1726/

Comment: That is actually what I ended up doing. Thanks. Oh, BTW, you forgot to include the responsive stylesheet in the fiddle. I updated it. You must use the center panel slider to test the responsive layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You have to break this in to two rows, and let the  left row that has labels be something like

span2, span2, span2, span4, span2

and then second row will contain input typesin the same manner

span2, span2, span2, span4, span2

I know it will look odd, but it will be responsive. You have to go with the Idea that Labels will always remain as a heading and can't break in to their respective input types. But that's the give and take when you switch to responsive layouts.

Comment: He already has it as two rows, and it doesn't work - see the comments.