# Bootstrap inputs overflowing the container

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a bit of an issue with Bootstrap forms. I have a span6 as a container and as soon as the page is resized then the form elements break out of that span6.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. I'm trying to avoid placing span elements directly on the inputs because that is not the ideal way to fix this and I have also tried placing spans on the control groups, the controls and so forth. I just cant seem to figure this out.

My html

```
<div class="mainReg">
<div class="span6">
<div class="regBlock">
  <h3>Create an Account</h3>
  <div style="padding: 5px 5px 10px 15px;">
    <p>Your journey to becoming a published author begins here! Create an account to take advantage of the free publishing services offered on FreeChristianPublishing.com.</p>
  </div>
  <form id="formID" onsubmit="return jQuery(this).validationEngine('validate');" method="post" action="/process.php">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">First Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input class="validate[required]" type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Last Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input class="validate[required]" type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email Address</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input class="validate[required,custom[email]]" type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Verify Email Address</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input class="validate[required,equals[email]]" type="text" name="email2" id="email2" value="" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Password</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input class="validate[required] minSize[6]" type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Verify Password</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input class="validate[required,equals[password]]" type="password" name="password2" id="password2" value="" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <label class="checkbox">
          <input class="validate[required]" type="checkbox" id="agree_to_terms" name="agree_to_terms" value="1" <?=$CHECKED?> /> I agree to the <a href="" target="_blank">terms &amp; conditions</a>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
          <label class="checkbox">
          <input class="validate[required]" type="checkbox" id="over_18" name="over_18" value="1" <?=$CHECKED?> /> I am over 18 years old.
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--.regBlock-->
  </div>
  <!--.span6-->
</div>
<!--.mainReg-->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/N8cjB/4/

Comment: @danrhul all the boostrap elements are still not working though. Such as span6 and the input elements...which is what I'm trying to work with

Comment: Danrhul attached Bootstrap 3 files, which use a different grid. Stand by.

Comment: Fiddle updated above. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/N8cjB/4/

Comment: Look at the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305719/bootstrap-responsive-horizontal-layout Instead of using form-horizontal, use nested columns that naturally wrap when needed.

Comment: That was what I originally had, but my boss changed it over to the form horizontal and I cant change it. :/

Answer (score 0):

You've set your column width too narrow for what you're containing. Either set a wider column, or change the media queries to go full-width sooner, or make your form elements smaller for smaller screen sizes.

Comment: I can't change my column width or else the form take up the whole page and I already having it go to s span 12 when the browser reaches 1060, I can't make it full width any sooner. And it's a span6, that should be plenty of room, thats half the page!

Comment: Yes, but half a page isn't enough at some screen sizes, as you've seen.

Comment: I could see that if I was looking at an ipad or something small, but this is a 1300px browser. It shouldn't be doing that at this size

Comment: I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding about how responsive works. I'm not sure what else to say.

Comment: For me, the .span6 col doesn't become too small for your form until the 960px width point. Chrome/Win7.

Comment: I completely understand how responsive works, thank you very much. That is all I do everyday all day. I normally do not work with this form and that is where my problem is.

Comment: I did not include my entire website in the jsfiddle, I have other constrains on the form  and it sits beside something else.